# Laravel livewire weird behaviour with tinyMCE

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

It's now 3 days that I'm stuck on the samme issue and i cannot figure out a solution.

I'm building a livewire dashboard with nested components.

The structure i hav at the moment where I'm having issues is the following :

```
View 
 Livewire component [main]
  Livewire component [card] in @foreach
   Livewire component [modal-details]
    Livewire component [template-editor]
```

And these are my actual components

```
@livewire('settings.templates.main')
@foreach($scheduled as $message)
   <livewire:settings.templates.scheduled-task-card :message="$message" wire:key="{{$message->id. $loop->index}}">
@endforeach
<livewire:settings.templates.modal-details :template="$template" wire:key="{{$template->id. 'modal'}}">
<livewire:settings.templates.template-editor :template="$template" wire:key="{{$template->id.'editor'}}">
```

**ISSUE**

The `template-editor` component  is the following, and it's including a tinyMCE editor :

BLADE VIEW

```
    <textarea id="editor" wire:model.lazy="content" class="mt-3 w-full" wire:key="{{$template->id . 'editor-templates'}}">
    </textarea>
    <div wire:loading class="ml-2">
        <svg role="status" class="inline w-6 h-6 mr-2 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-indigo-600" viewBox="0 0 100 101" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        </svg>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

CLASS

```
class TemplateEditor extends Component
{
    public $content;
    public $template;

    public function mount($template){
        $this->template = $template;

        if(!$this->template->body == null){
            $this->content = $this->template->body;
        }
    }


    public function updated(){

        $item = Template::find($this->template->id);
        $item->body = $this->content;
        $item->save();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.tenant.settings.templates.template-editor');
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm facing is that the editor, independently from which card I open, is updating the body property only of the first record and not of the respective record as I would expect.

But things become more weird when i noticed that on first load, the component is retrieving data from the correct record, in fact, in `$content` variable is stored the correct value; but, if i try to delete that value and replace it with a new one, it's going to be updated in the record 1 of the table, even if I'm on editor referred to another record.

Did anybody face the same issue before? If s, how did you solve?

Thanky you

Comment: Usually such a weird things are happening when there are some problems with :wire:key - it's not unique or not properly set. At first I would recommend to check and ensure that all components have unique wire key. The second thing, is that livewire components are not reactive like in vue or react. In one of the discussions there was proposed a workaround to force component re-render on update. Try to add now() to each wire key as an addition and check. E.g. wire:key="{{now() .$template->id.'editor'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell Livewire to ignore changes to a subset of HTML within your component, you can add the `wire:ignore` [directive](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#ignoring-dom-changes).

For example livewire will ignore this tinymce editor. So the editor will not show any bad behaviour.

```
    <div class="mb-6" wire:ignore>
         <label for="myeditorinstance" class="label">CONTENT</label>
                
           <x-tinymce.tinymce-editor />
    </div>
```